# 24 averages for values in array based on what hour they are in

Tags: f#

I have a record that holds one DateTime array and 2 double arrays all of the same length and related by index.

I want to get the average of the delta between the 2 double arrays based the hour of the DateTime. So I'll have 24 averages in the end. All data in index 0 of the arrays are related / happen at the same time, and so on for all the indexes. Perhaps I should instead have 1 array of tuples or records that each holds just one datetime, and 2 doubles.

But anyway this is what I have so far:

```
let data2 = [ for i in 0..data.Date.Length-1 do
                                    yield data.Date.[i].Hour, data.High.[i] - data.Low.[i]]
```

And here is where my inexperience hurts the most. The only thing I can think of is to do some kind of matching or if statements that go through all of those 24 hours (0 - 23) and having individual mutable values for each hour. There must be an easier way. I've been unsuccessful so far in finding a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do

```
let grouped = data2 |> Seq.GroupBy (fst) |> Seq.map (fun (a,b) -> Seq.average (b |> Seq.map (snd)))
```

Here `Seq.groupBy` will group all the elements which have an identical first element.  You can then take the average with `Seq.average`.

Note:

I think your original expression for data2 would be better written as

```
data.Date |> Array.mapi (fun i t -> t.Hour,data.High.[i]-data.Low.[i])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is definitely close to correct however I get the error "Expecting a type supporting the operator '+' but given a tuple type" -- This error points to the last b after Seq.average

Comment: Because b has type int * double, so I need to go into that and average the second value it appears. I'll see if I can't figure it out and then report here.

Comment: Sorry for the endless comments. Its weird how groupBy doesn't remove the original hours and represents them all just once. Instead it represents them twice each: (hour, [(hour, value); (hour, value) ]). That is nasty. Surely we need only one hour value for each, and then an array of values. I'll see if I can't get some practice by re implementing this function.